# Is it possible that intermittent current is being passed in a circuit with loose connections at less than maximum capacity?

Tags: electric-circuits

In a circuit, the wires may not have been connected properly and a connection is loose somewhere. Is it possible that intermittent current is being passed in a circuit at less than maximum capacity?

Comment: What do you mean by *"being passed at less than maximum capacity"*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind - He/she probably means that if $1$ mA passes through a node with proper connections, will something like $0.1$ mA still pass with loose (on and off) connections.

Comment: We can split it into two - when it is off, nothing passes :)

Comment: @New_new_newbie will the less current pass with loose connections as stated in your first comment or will it not pass at all with loose connections?

Comment: Like I said, if we resolve into two parts, it looks like all or none to me, in the respective cases. But you use the phrase "intermittent current" in the Q, so that probably means when what happens when it goes from on to off. I don't know for sure what happens here, so you see why I'm reluctant to post an answer and am commenting instead. :)